# Error while previewing the Sitecore item/Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: training-certification

Whenever I am trying to preview homepage, this is the screen that I am seeing, but when I open the same page in the experience editor, the homepage does open, why am I not able to check the preview. And this happens not just with the homepage, but with every item in the Sitecore tree.

[image]

**Edit #1**
I am using Sitecore Rocks Version 4.0.2,here is a screenshot of the same: 
[image]

Comment: You rock @x3mxray, it works after changes to browse.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in file *"WebService/Browse.aspx"*. This is **Sitecore Rocks** service.

As I see on your screenshot you are using **Sitecore version 9.3**. Parameterless constructor for **LoggedInArgs** was obsolete in sitecore 9 and *completely removed* in 9.3.

It seems that you use **old version** of Sitecore Rocks. Just install the latest version (or remove it at all if you dont need it and the error will disappear).

*Sitecore Rocks versions 4.x are compatible with Sitecore 9.3*

https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/releases

**Edit #1**
I downloaded and extracted Browse.aspx from latest version - it uses **LoggingInArgs()** without params. *Looks like Sitecore Rocks bug.*

[image]

**Edit #2:**
I installed latest version of Sitecore Rocks on my clear Sitecore 9.3 to test this issue.

[image]

**BUT**

When I navigate to page preview in sitecore it works good:

[image]

It is because *Browse.aspx* should not be hitted from sitecore.
This issue is reproduced only by opening browser from **Sitecore Rocks in Visual Studio**.

[image]

**Solution:**

You can fix it manually by adding current **HttpContext** as a parameter.
Open **sitecore\shell\WebService\Browse.aspx** and add **Request.RequestContext.HttpContext** as a parameter in line 43:

```
var args2 = new Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInArgs(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext);
```

It is tested and works good for me.

Comment: I am using Sitecore rocks version 4.0.2, but still upvoted. might be useful for others.

Comment: You are rigth. I downloaded and extracted Browse.aspx from latest version - it uses LoggingInArgs() without params. Looks like Sitecore Rocks bug. It would be nice if your open an issue https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/issues

Comment: Add a hotfix to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton, x3mxray, this fix worked perfectly, so glad we have such dedicated people like you in our community :)

Comment: I have also logged a ticket, so that we don't have this bug in further versions :)

Comment: Here is the ticket for this bug: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/issues/141

Comment: The same issue is with sitecore back office now!! I am able to preview stuff from sitecore rocks but not from backoffice