# Sitecore preview redirects to desktop

Tags: experience-editor

Extending below issue to the preview option from `Sitecore V9.3 back office`.

[Error while previewing the Sitecore item/Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24239/error-while-previewing-the-sitecore-item-sitecore-pipelines-loggedin-loggedinarg)

Whenever any item is previewed from back-office, it redirects to the desktop. If the same item is opened in the experience editor, it appears fine.

**EDIT #1**

All the required content is already published in the web database. And the whole home root folder of the site is there.

Comment: what URL you are getting when you open it in preview?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the enablePreview property under Sitecore.config file. It should be set to true like this.

```
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" />
```

When you make it false, it doesn't allow you to preview the page. But you can open it in experience editor.